# How to determine from which url a PHP header was called

Tags: php, http-headers

I've got a page under http://www.example.com/abc/def/a/ where a user can buy products.
For a marketing activity (printed paper) the customer should type in a shorter url
http://www.example.com/order/

When this url is called, the server executes this script:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.de/abc/def/a/");
exit;
?>
```

The page under http://www.example.com/abc/def/a/ contains some
informations (rebate-code etc.) which should only be visible to users
coming from http://www.example.com/order/

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` seems to be not reliable from what I've read.

I checked with `phpinfo();` if there is any info variable which contains "order" but I haven't found one.

Is it possible or do you recommend an alternative approach?

Comment: I would use PHP Sessions to track user moves.

Comment: Just forgot about sessions...must be my age ;) ty for the hints. Just implemented - works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is in it's pure form a *stateless-protocol*, so you won't find anything in the protocol itself that will help you with your current problem.

Using `$_SESSION` to store data in-between requests is the easiest route to walk, and what I recommend.

As said; since the protocol used to transfer information is *stateless* you have no choice but to create a method for your web-application to recognize which request is done by which user.. this is a perfect problem solved by php-sessions.

---

- **[php.net - PHP: Sessions - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)**

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, the HTTP Referer, along with all of the other headers, can easily be faked. The only reliable way I see of accomplishing this is logging users as they visit the orders page and when they visit the `/abc/def/a/` page, verify that the log entry exists. This kind of log could be stored in `$_SESSION`, however be sure that when using multiple servers you have the proper setup to ensure all servers share the same session information (you can use a [redis server to store session data](http://redis4you.com/articles.php?id=001&name=Redis%20as%20session%20handler%20in%20PHP)).

On the order page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['order_visited'] = true;
```

On the rebate code page:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['order_visited']) || !$_SESSION['order_visited']) {
    header('Location: /order'); // Must visit order first
    die();
}
```